# Proof for nonexistance of a partial limit

Tags: calculus

I would like to verify the correctness of my proof for part b of the question (assume part a was proved). Thanks

**Question:**
$a_n $is a sequence s.t. $0,2 \in P(a_n)$ and $\forall n \in \Bbb N: |a_n-a_{n+1}|<1$

a. Prove that the sequence has another partial limit L.

b. Does $a_n$ have exactly 3 partial limits?

**Proof for b:**
* We assume $a_n$ has only 3 partial limits: 0,2,L.

- From part a of the question: 0 < L < 2 (Otherwise the distance between two adjacant items in $a_n$ will be greater than 1).
- $\Rightarrow \forall \varepsilon>0 \exists N_1 \in \Bbb N \forall n>N_1 : |a_{n_l}|<\varepsilon$
- $\Rightarrow \forall \varepsilon>0 \exists N_2 \in \Bbb N \forall n>N_2 : |a_{n_k}-2|<\varepsilon$
- From Bolzano Weierstrass: $\exists a_{n_j} \to L \Rightarrow  \forall \varepsilon>0 \exists N_3 \in \Bbb N \forall n>N_3 : |a_{n_j}-2|<\varepsilon$
- Similarly to what I've done before: $N_4 = max ${$N_1,N_2, N_3$}
- So from $N_4$ onward: There exists an item $a_n $ s.t. $a_{n+1}\in$ *(one of the 3 sub sequences)*$ \Rightarrow $

  - from the definition of partial limits we have an infinite number of items that satisfy : 
    $$2-\varepsilon < a_{n_k} <2+\varepsilon $$
    $$L-\varepsilon < a_{n_j} <L+\varepsilon $$
    $$0-\varepsilon < a_{n_l} <0+\varepsilon $$
- From combining the inequalities, we get 6 possible options for ${a_{n+1}}-{a_n}$:

$$2-L < a_{n_k} -a_{n_j} < 2-L \Rightarrow a_{n_k} -a_{n_j} = 2-L
 <1 \Rightarrow L >1 $$
$$L-2 < a_{n_j} -a_{n_k} < L-2 \Rightarrow a_{n_j} -a_{n_k} = L-2<1 \Rightarrow L < 3 \Rightarrow L<2$$ ( we assumed 0  < L< 2)
$$L < a_{n_j} -a_{n_l} < L \Rightarrow a_{n_j} -a_{n_l} = L <1 $$(this is a contradiction to the first case)
$$-L < a_{n_l} -a_{n_j} < -L \Rightarrow a_{n_l} -a_{n_j} = -L <1 \Rightarrow L>1 $$(contradiction to the 3rd case)
$$2 < a_{n_k} -a_{n_l} < 2 \Rightarrow a_{n_k} -a_{n_l} = 2 <1  $$(contradiction)
$$-2 < a_{n_l} -a_{n_k} < -2 \Rightarrow a_{n_l} -a_{n_k} = -2 <1 $$

From these contradictions we see that a case where there is only one L besides 0,2 is impossible (L cannot be bigger and smaller than 1 at the same time)

Comment: What is $P(a_n)$?

Comment: the set of all partial limits of a_n

Comment: You're correct.

Answer (score 4):

In your attempted proof, you treat the $\pm\epsilon$ wrongly when adding inequalities. Check that again.
Also, it is not *immediately* conclusive that you should find three subsequences that together make up the full sequence; it is at least not true for any subsequence the existence of which is guaranteed by Bolzano-Weierstrass.

---

It is *possible* that $(a_n)$ has exactly three partial limits $0$, $1$, and $2$:
$$a_n= \begin{cases}1&\text{if } n \equiv 0\pmod 2,\\2-\tfrac1n&\text{if }n\equiv 1\pmod 4,\\\tfrac1n&\text{if }n\equiv 3\pmod 4.\end{cases}$$
Note that $|a_n-a_{n+1}|=1-\frac1n<1$ if $n$ is odd and $|a_n-a_{n+1}|=1-\frac1{n+1}<1$ if $n$ is even.

It is also *possible* than there are more partial limits.
In fact, 
$$ a_n=1+\sin n$$
has all points in $[0,2]$ as partial limits.

So the answer is: No, $a_n$ does not *necessarily* have exactly three partial limits.

Comment: Nice.....+1....

Comment: Great answer. Could you please elaborate what I did wrong with the epsilons? And also, I'm assuming that there are only 3 partial limits, so doesn't this assumption come with a possibility that all available indexes belong to one of the 3 sub sequences? (Do I have to do it like you did, with dividing N to groups)?

Comment: Would really love an answer :-)